# Diminish flyspell

Tags: mode-line

How can I diminish flyspell-mode (the one built-in to emacs)? With use-package, none of the following work:

```
(use-package flyspell-mode
  :diminish)

(use-package flyspell-mode
  :diminish 'flyspell-mode)

(use-package flyspell-mode
  :config
  (eval-after-load "flyspell". '(diminish 'flyspell-mode)))
```

I would like to diminish flyspell-mode everywhere, but particularly in org buffers.

This is the full package configuration:

```
(use-package flyspell-mode
  :init
  (setq flyspell-issue-message-flag nil) 

  :hook ; Enable flyspell in specific modes
  (text-mode  org-mode  change-log-mode-hook  log-edit-mode-hook)

  :diminish 'flyspell-mode
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also trying to find a solution to this problem. It appears that adding this to my init solves it:

```
(setq flyspell-mode-line-string nil)
```

Inspecting `minor-mode-alist`, it turns out that for `flyspell-mode` its value is set to `flyspell-mode-line-string`.

```
Value:
((diff-minor-mode " Diff")
 (flyspell-mode flyspell-mode-line-string)
 (ispell-minor-mode " Spell")
 (highlight-indent-guides-mode #1="")
```

I think this "confuses" `diminish`, and hence, the mode is not "diminished".

Comment: jrdpastors' answer successfully diminished "Fly" from my mode line. Note: the line `(setq flyspell-mode-line-string nil)` had to be added outside the use-package block for flyspell-mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```el
(use-package flyspell
  :diminish 'flyspell-mode)
```

It wants the mode that is provided by `flyspell`, which is called `flyspell-mode`.

Without `use-package`:

```el
(require 'flyspell)
(diminish 'flyspell-mode)
```

Comment: Still no success. Could it be related to the sequence in which packages and modes are loaded? Diminish works for everything else in my config.el.

Comment: Hmmm, that's taken right out of my config. Did you use-package/require diminish before this code?

Comment: Yes, `(require 'diminish)` is in my init.el, and precedes flyspell. Every other mode seems to diminish successfully

Comment: By the way, in the use-package line, if I use `flyspell` as in your example instead of `flyspell-mode` as in my example, I receive the error: `File mode specification error: (error Autoloading failed to define function flyspell)` Could this be a clue? In fact, there is no flyspell package in my elpa directory, yet flyspell-mode works.

Comment: I honestly have no idea why your `(use-package flyspell-mode)` does not throw an error; I do not know of a package called "flyspell-mode". I've edited to use `require`, only. Let me know if that works. If it does, then there is something fugazi, here.